# submit button for jquery dependent dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, drop-down-menu

Hey everyone so I recently had to finish up some code for a multi-level dropdown menu - the majority of the code is from a previous developer and I'm pretty unfamiliar with Jquery itself so it's been giving me a lot of trouble.

Basically what i need to happen is when the user selects the option from the last dropdown, they then click a button, and a specific page opens up  depending on the information of the last dropdown. What currently happens is the moment they select the last option the page automatically launches. All my attempts to get a button work with the code have been rather useless - although again, it's something I have very little knowledge of.

Any help would be majorly appreciated

here's all the code I currently have below (cut down the number of entries per dropdown level but otherwise is the exact same):

Jquery:

```
$(function(){

  var $cat = $("#category1"),
      $subcat = $("#category2"),
      $volt = $("#category3");

      $cat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
        $subcat.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
        $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
      });

      $subcat.on("change",function(){
      debugger;
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $volt.find("option").attr("style","");
        $volt.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $volt.prop("disabled",true);
        $volt.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $volt.prop("disabled",false);
      });

});
```

My css:

```
#category2 option{
    display:none;
}

#category2 option.label{
    display:block;
}

#category3 option{
    display:none;
}

#category3 option.label{
    display:block;
}
```

and the webpage code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">First Dropdown Menu:</td>
<td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
<select name="category1" id="category1">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Option1">ONE</option>
                  <option value="Option2">TWO</option>
                  <option value="Option3">THREE</option>
                  <option value="Option4">FOUR</option>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
<form id="formname1" name="formname1" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
<tr>
          <td align="right" valign="middle">Second Dropdown Menu:</td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle">
              <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
                  <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
<!-- R -->
<option rel="Option1" value="R12">12</option>
<option rel="Option1" value="R24">24</option>
<option rel="Option1" value="R36">36</option>
                  <option rel="Option1" value="R48">48</option>
                  <option rel="Option1" value="R80">80</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<form id="formname2" name="formname2" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
<tr>
          <td align="right" valign="middle">Third Dropdown Menu</td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle">
              <select disabled="disabled" id="category3" name="category3">
<option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
<!-- R -->
                  <option rel="R12" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com">R12V1</option>
                  <option rel="R24" value="http://www.yourwebsite1.com">R24V1</option>
                  <option rel="R36" value="http://www.yourwebsite2.com">R36V1</option>
                  <option rel="R48" value="http://www.yourwebsite3.com">R48V1</option>
              </select>
</td>
</tr>
      <script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'category3' );
 urlmenu.onsubmit = function() {
  window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script>  
  </table>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like all you need to do is add a button with an onclick listener (and some input handling) and read the value from the 3rd dropdown. The button will be disabled until the 3rd dropdown has a value. It will disabled again if the user selects "Please Select"

I also fixed a few bugs with user input when they reselect "Please Select" the below selects should be disabled again (as well as the submit button)

And remove this code from the html file which looks like it is doing the redirecting when the 3rd option is selected

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'category3' );
 urlmenu.onsubmit = function() {
  window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script>
```

Here is an example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $cat = $("#category1"),
    $subcat = $("#category2"),
    $volt = $("#category3"),
    $submitButton = $("#submitButton");

  $cat.on("change", function() {
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style", "");
    $subcat.val("");
    $volt.val("");
    $submitButton.prop("disabled", true);
    if (!_rel) {
      $subcat.prop("disabled", true);
      $volt.prop("disabled", true);
      return;
    }
    $subcat.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled", false);
  });

  $subcat.on("change", function() {
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $volt.find("option").attr("style", "");
    $volt.val("");
    $submitButton.prop("disabled", true)
    if (!_rel) {
      $volt.prop("disabled", true);
      return;
    }
    $volt.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
    $volt.prop("disabled", false);
  });

  $volt.on("change", function() {
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    if (!_rel) {
      $submitButton.prop("disabled", true);
      return;
    }
    $submitButton.prop("disabled", false); // allow the user to submit
  });

  $submitButton.on("click", function() {
    console.log("Send me to: " + $volt.val());
    // window.open( $volt.val() );
  });
});
```

```css
#category2 option {
  display: none;
}

#category2 option.label {
  display: block;
}

#category3 option {
  display: none;
}

#category3 option.label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp">
  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">First Dropdown Menu:</td>
      <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
        <select name="category1" id="category1">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="Option1">ONE</option>
          <option value="Option2">TWO</option>
          <option value="Option3">THREE</option>
          <option value="Option4">FOUR</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <form id="formname1" name="formname1" method="post" action="submitform.asp">
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">Second Dropdown Menu:</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
          <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
            <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
            <!-- R -->
            <option rel="Option1" value="R12">12</option>
            <option rel="Option1" value="R24">24</option>
            <option rel="Option1" value="R36">36</option>
            <option rel="Option1" value="R48">48</option>
            <option rel="Option1" value="R80">80</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <form id="formname2" name="formname2" method="post" action="submitform.asp">
        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="middle">Third Dropdown Menu</td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <select disabled="disabled" id="category3" name="category3">
              <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
              <!-- R -->
              <option rel="R12" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com">R12V1</option>
              <option rel="R24" value="http://www.yourwebsite1.com">R24V1</option>
              <option rel="R36" value="http://www.yourwebsite2.com">R36V1</option>
              <option rel="R48" value="http://www.yourwebsite3.com">R48V1</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button type="button" id="submitButton" disabled>Submit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I am having a few problems with this though. The button will appear and the dropdowns will still work, although the button stays grayed out and not clickable. If I change the script src on the page to the new one your provided (<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>) then everything stops working completely, no dropdowns, etc. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Rob The way I have the code to work is the button is greyed out until you select a value from all 3 dropdowns (I can help change this if you prefer). If you understand that, then do you get any console errors when you include the jQuery 2.1.1 script and open the html page? in Chrome you can open the console hitting F12

Comment: The button being greyed out until a value is selected is great! It just wouldn't un-grey for me even with the value selected. When i open the console it's just a blank box. Thanks for all the help by the way!

Comment: what about when you click the "Run Code Snippet" in my answer above? Does it work when you try there? also what browser are you using?

Comment: Running code snippet works - when i click submit it shows a message send me to: (website address). I'm mainly using chrome but i've checked on safari & firefox as well and gotten similar results.

Comment: I edited my answer to include wrapping the jquery code in a `$( document ).ready(function() {});` see if that works for your env. If its working here and not in your env, then something is off about how your env is setup

Comment: Hey so I managed to sort of make it work - instead of the link you had for the ajax.googapis, I made a copy of that file and put it up on my site. Now the dropdown menu works correctly and the button un-greys when I click the last option, but clicking on the button does not launch the new page.

Comment: in the console it will show send me to: (website address) however it doesn't actually direct me there in the browser, if that helps. if i click on the thescript.js:45 next to that, it shows the part of file console.log("Send me to: " + $volt.val()); . Is there another step to get it to actually open up the page? Thanks again by the way, your help has been majorly appreciated.

Comment: hey glad I could help! so in my code I commented out `// window.open( $volt.val() );` You should uncomment that for the url to open. I only commented it because it didn't make sense for this example

Comment: That worked! Huge thanks, you were really a life-saver on this one. I noticed the window doesn't seem to open on Safari, although it seems to work on all other browsers I tried (which is hugely helpful) - does safari require it to be coded in a special way?

Comment: no problem, glad its working for you! Safari looks a bit different with its built in ad blockers probably messing with you. If you look around stack overflow you'll find similar problems. The solution is to window.open in an onclick (user) event (which we are doing here) so not sure why its still not working.